# Tokenizing User Input in Python

Tags: python

Its been a while since I last really used python. How do you tokenize a user input?

Lets say for example:
User input: Hey my name is Jon

Tokenizer will split it based on the spaces

Comment: are you just looking for `str.split()`?

Comment: Something like that but I want it to be like a look so at every instance Tok will have the value of a character from the string. For example: while token is not null, push that value to a stack @cmd

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: lol not at all man I just wanted to know about a function and how it works. I can write the code myself @HenryKeiter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use group of regex to tokenize a string:

```
import re

tokens = (
  ('STRING', re.compile('"[^"]+"')),  # longest match
  ('ID', re.compile('[a-zA-Z_]+')),
  ('SPACE', re.compile('\s+')),
  ('DIGIT', re.compile('\d+')),
)

def tokenizer(s):
  i = 0
  lexeme = []
  while i < len(s):
    match = False
    for token, regex in tokens:
      result = regex.match(s, i)
      if result:
        lexeme.append((token, result.group(0)))
        i = result.end()
        match = True
        break
    if not match:
      raise Exception('lexical error at {0}'.format(i))
  return lexeme
```

with the string `abcd xvc  23432 "exampe" 366`:

```
for i in tokenizer('abcd xvc  23432 "exampe" 366'):
  print i
```

prints:

```
('ID', 'abcd')
('SPACE', ' ')
('ID', 'xvc')
('SPACE', '  ')
('DIGIT', '23432')
('SPACE', ' ')
('STRING', '"exampe"')
('SPACE', ' ')
('DIGIT', '366')
```

Comment: Yes! This was actually what I was looking for thanks!

Comment: What if I want to check the type of the token lets say before I try to do an addition. How do you do that? @BSH

Comment: @MannyO `isinstance(obj,type)` returns `True` if `obj` inherits `type` anywhere. Alternatively, just check the first index in `i` (e.g. `i[0]`) and check it against `"ID"`,`"SPACE"`,`"DIGIT"`, or `"STRING"`

Comment: @MannyO for instance using this code you could do `for type_,value in tokenizer: if type_=="DIGIT": 12345+int(value)`

Comment: Ohh I get it, one last question. Im trying to use a list as a stack in python, but the order the values are getting pushed are in reverse(or atleast thats the way they print) how do I print it in the LIFO (Last In First Out) way? @adsmith

Comment: @MannyO You can check the token, `ID`, `SPACE`, `STRING` ...

Comment: @MannyO I'll defer to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks) for that, which actually has a specific section for your use case.

Comment: @MannyO Though I might note that `for x in lst` is bad form if you're modifying the list during iteration. You could do `for x in lst[:]` which will iterate through a copy of the list! Or even the incredibly unpythonic `for _ in range(len(lst))`

Comment: @MannyO Although probably the most "pythonic" way to treat a list as LIFO is to iterate through it as `for x in lst[::-1]` or `for x in reversed(lst)`!

Comment: Oh yea thats the one I was looking for. Once again, thanks a bunch man! God Bless @adsmith

Answer (score 0):

Use split for splitting a string

```
str.split()
```

Comment: Yea but lets say there is a number in there, how do I specify it individually as a number before pushing it to a stack @Amit

Answer (score 0):

```
> "Hey my name is Jon".split() -
['Hey', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'Jon']
```

would be the easy answer. If you have a more complicated notion of token (for instance, should "Jon!" be 1 or 2 tokens) use `re.findall`.

```
> re.findall(r'(\d+)|(\w+)', 'Jon is 10 years old')
[('', 'Jon'), ('', 'is'), ('10', ''), ('', 'years'), ('', 'old')]
```

Note that this puts numbers on the left of each tuple and other strings on the right. This will do other things you may not have expected

```
> re.findall(r'(\d+)|(\w+)', 'Hi-yoo')
[('', 'Hi'), ('', 'yoo')]
```

Look up a nice regex tutorial to learn more.

Comment: Yea but lets say there is a number in there, how do I specify it individually as a number before pushing it to a stack @U2EF1

Comment: @MannyO maybe something like `[int(token) if token.isdigit() else token for token in user_input.split()]`

Comment: @MannyO What adsmith said, also if this is getting more complicated, look up how to use regex groups.

Comment: I sort of understand but can you show an example using python syntax please @adsmith

Comment: @MannyO that's valid python code. It's called a list comprehension.

Comment: @MannyO You can also bury them in `for` loops and use an accumulator if you want to be more explicit. `tokens = []; for token in user_input.split(): # do type checking, convert however you like, and tokens.append(token)`

Comment: oh ok so does the split() function in python work the same as the strtok() function in C. Where it takes the user input and sets each token to a variable. Example tok = strtok(buffer," "); tok holds the words from buffer that are separated by spaces @adsmith

Comment: I don't know C, so I couldn't compare the two. `str.split(sep)` takes the `str` and creates a list of `str`s. Each element in the new list was separated from the last by `sep` in the original `str`. By default, `sep == " "`

Comment: hmmm ok I get it now, im just trying to figure out how I can use it for my situation. Thanks alot tho u guys. Very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.split()` to do this, but that removes spaces. In case you want to preserve the spaces, use `list(str)`.